# Trying to populate my *urL with the contents of the picker view

Tags: xcode, video, playback, uipicker

Hi could anyone help me , im trying to populate my *URL with the contents of the picker view so i can use selected pickerview row to link to play the selected  video . i.e.: if pickerview is showing "vid 1" then pressing the UIRecbutton labelled "play vid"  would play vid 1, ect.. any help greatly appreciated , anyone who helps automatically goes on my mental "who gets some money if i win the lottery" list lol. cheers franco

PS: i  have all code set up apart from how to get picker view info from the pickerview to vid player. the default is:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Video1" ofType:@"MOV"]];
```

just to give a path name, if the row in pickerview reads Video1, video2 ect.. how to i get this info to the pathforresource & have it default to movie type, i.e.: mov, mpeg4 .

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `selectedRowInComponent`.  It will return which row is currently selected in your picker.  Then run an `if` block on the return value, and set up your url filename and path from that (actually, a `switch` would prob be better for lots of items in your picker).   Assuming you only have 1 segment in your UIPickerView (as in only 1 wheel to spin, whereas a date picker would have 3 segments, one for month, one for day, one for year), what you want might look something like:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    NSString *fileName;
    NSString *fileType;
    switch ([myPicker selectedRowInComponent:0])
    {
        case 0:
            fileName = @"Video1";
            fileType = @"mov";
            break;
        case 1:
            fileName = @"Video2";
            fileType = @"mpeg4";
            break;
        //more cases here depending on how many items are in your UIPickerView

        default:
            break;

    }
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:fileName ofType:fileType]];

    //put in your code to play the video in myURL here
}
```